# Nested list django

Tags: python, django, list, nested, django-queryset

Assuiming

I have a one to Many model like this:

```
class User(models.Model):
     username = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class UserComment(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User)
     text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

How can I make a queryset in the django view in order to have a list like the following?

```
user_comments= [[username1, [text1, text2, text3]], [username2, [text1, text2]]]
```

**----UPDATE----**

I ended up using a slightly modified version of Sander van Leeuwen solution

**views.py**

```
user_comments = {}
user_comments = Comments.objects.select_related('envia')
comments_by_user = collections.defaultdict(list)
for comment in user_comments:
  comments_by_user[comment.envia.id].append([comment.envia.first_name+" "+comment.envia.last_name,comment.text,comment.date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')])
comments_by_user.default_factory = None
```

**template.html**

```
{% for key, values in comments_by_user.items %}
<ul class="chat-history" id="{{key}}-hist">
    {% for val in values%} 
        <li class="opponent unread">
        {% for v in val %}
            {%if forloop.counter = 1 %}
            <span class="user">{{v}}</span>
            {% elif forloop.counter = 2 %}
            <p>{{v}}</p>
            {% elif forloop.counter = 3 %}
            <span class="time">{{v}}</span>
            {%endif%}
        {% endfor %}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a reason that you want nested lists?

A dict would be easier to deal with. For example:

```
user_comments = UserComment.objects.select_related('user')
comments_by_user = defaultdict(list)
for comment in users_comments:
    comments_by_user[comment.user.username].append(comment.text)
```

This will output:

```
{'username1': ['comment', 'comment', ...], 'username2': ['comment', 'comment']}
```

If you really want nested lists you can do:

```
comments_list = [[username, comments] for username, comments in comments_by_user.items()]
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
user_comments = []
for comment in UserComment.objects.select_related('user') \
                                  .order_by('user__username'):
    if user_comments and user_comments[-1][0] == comment.user.username:
        user_comments[-1][1].append(comment.text)
    else:
        user_comments.append([comment.user.username, [comment.text]])
```